# Lost Calendar in Thunderbird after Ubuntu 18.04 System Update

Tags: updates, thunderbird, calendar

I recently ran the offered system update for my Ubuntu 18.04 installation.  Everything appeared to go well even if it did take over an hour and I was quite happy whit how it all turned out.  However I've just noticed that the calendar that I was running in Thunderbird 60.20.1  has disappeared.  This is a real pain as I use the calendar a lot and have a lot of reminders set in it.

Can anyone advise; Has the calendar just been de-activated and can be re-activated?  If so how do I do it?  Or  Have I lost everything and have to start again?

Comment: If you were using the Lightning add-on (quite likely), it got deactivated because it is incompatible with Thunderbird 60. In this case, there isn't much you can do except wait for an upgrade from Lightning.

Comment: Not so, @Aimery! The fix is in the suggested duplicate question.